# In Quarriors, can the Portal Dice be used multiple times?

Tags: quarriors

Say I've culled most of my dice. I have 3 portals, 3 basic quiddity dice and 1 assistant.
I draw all but 2 portals from my bag, and the one portal die I do draw I roll a "2 portal". I draw two portals from my bag and roll them, and put the portal die I just used into my Used pile. Both portal dice come up "2 portal" I set one in my used pile, and refill my bag from my used pile.

I imagine you can see where this is going. Is it okay to tournament-short-cut 2 of the three portal dice to "1 quiddity" and then roll the last one? Or can dice rolled this turn not go back in the bag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the Quarmageddon expansion, the [rulebook](http://wizkidsgames.com/wp-content/uploads/quarma/QuarmageddonRulebook.pdf) has been **updated**. The change is this: dice (such as Portals) that are spent during the turn are placed into a separate Spent Pile, where they are ineligible to be put back into the bag until the end of the turn. This is a change from the earlier FAQ, and makes it much less likely that in the given situation, the Portals would end up producing Quiddity.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually shortcut all three of them to 1 Quiddity.

I had a similar question myself, and found on another forum the official answer from a representative from Wizkids, the game publisher (released 8/15/2011):

> [Q) Can portals keep pulling themselves?](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/686929/wizkids-faq-8152011)
>
> A) Yes, but if you are only pulling portals, the player may declare that the end state of 1 Quiddity is reached and not have to keep rolling them (simulate infinite rolls)."

The moment you try to use your first +2 portal, it goes into the used pile. Since now you have two dice in your bag/used pile (the portal you pulled on the first go plus the one you just used), you can reroll them. At this point you're only pulling portals, so you can actually shortcut all three of them and get the +3 total Quiddity you want.

Comment: This is no longer the case as with the release of the Quarmageddon expansion, there was a rule change to introduce a Spent Area which lies between Active and Used.  Dice only go to the Used pile at the end of the turn.  So when you spend a Portal, it won't be returned to your bag for re-rolling purposes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when the bag needs to be drawn from and cannot be, the Used pile is emptied (same mechanic as in Dominion, from which it draws inspiration). In this case, it would seem like your portal dice will be re-rolled, moved to the Used pile and returned to the bag until you've rolled your Quiddity. Should you somehow have no dice in your Used pile OR in your bag and you need to draw, I say the drawing effect is lost.

Caveat: I've never played Quarriors, but I have read the rules (and look forward to playing it). I also know it's inspired by Dominion which I HAVE played. If it turns out I've totally misinterpreted the rules, be gentle, I'm only trying to help!

Comment: The rules seem to suggest that the Portal die you just used would go in the used pile before you put the used pile in the dice bag. However when it was demoed to me there was one instance where the demoer used a portal die and had an empty bag. He set the portal die aside, put the rest of his used pile in the bag, then put his portal die into a new used pile and then drew the 2 dice. I'm not sure that is really a citable source as for all I know he was a volunteer who had just learned the game that day.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I can't figure out why (in reality) you would only have the dice in your example. Because you only cull a die when you score with another die.  And your assistant is now the only score-able "creature" left in your pool...it could happen, but it shouldn't (if you actually want to win).

Anyhow, the rules states "immediate effects" such as Portals are resolved immediately and multiple immediate effects are resolved in any order you wish.  The 2 portal you rolled is  actively used to draw the two additional portals...after that it  would be moved to "Used" and could be drawn by one of the other portals, but one of your portals would alway be in play as a "portal"...

If the last portal roll came up as a 1 portal and the drawn die rolled 1 Quiddity.  You'd never get to that last portal in the bag.

So, since you can't guarantee the last "in-play" portal would alway roll a "2" portal when the others each rolled quiddity.  you could only  theoretically "short-circuit" one of the dice to the only non-portal action of 1 Quiddity.

Comment: The actual situation that came up a players deck was culled to 4 creatures (various), 1 assistant, and 3 portal dice. Since the creatures rolled where not important to the actual question I simplified the scenario a bit to avoid anyone being distracted by the fact that I had a wizard or dragon or whatever.